Edge browser proxy settings for Burp Suite
This is my case:
I'm using a webapp in a Docker container localhost:4280.
I want to test this webapp with Burp Suite (which listen to port 8080) and Microsoft Edge browser.
The way to set the proxy on Windows is Network & internet > Proxy > Use a proxy server and set to localhost 8080.
So far so good, but I see all the traffic in Burp Suite EXCEPT the webapp I need.

What could be the problem? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Is there a way to only send the webapp traffic to Burp Suite, and avoid everything else?


